# Changing date format stored as a String

Tags: android, datetime

Currently I store a date in my database in the following format

```
dbTimestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(myCalendar.getTime());
```

I am looking to pull this information in a cursor and display it to the user in the following format

```
String newTimestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(date);
```

How would I go about converting it from 2014-07-31 to 07/31/2014?

I tried using

```
String transactionDate = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("timestamp"));
String newTimestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(transactionDate);
```

But i get the following error: `Bad class: class java.lang.String`

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad class: class java.lang.String?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18528144/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-bad-class-class-java-lang-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try {
    String reformattedStr = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2014-07-31"));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Date date = new Date();
String get="" + dateFormat.format(date);
System.out.println("Test date is:"+get);
```