# Converting double to string with 2 decimals

Tags: java, android

i am being stuck at delicate problem with my fitness application.
Ive found many ways, how to convert my distance(double) output to string with 2 decimal places. Here comes the problem - when I want to print it to textview with format "%d" (as it has multiplication with integer), the application runs into IllegalFormatConversionException
Calories works just fine

Can anybody tell me what Iam doing wrong?

```
private int numSteps;
private double distance;
private double total_energy;
private double calories;
private int weight=80;

//Steps output
            count_steps.setText(String.valueOf(numSteps));
            numSteps++;

            //Distance output
            count_distance.setText(String.format("%d", distance + "m"));
            distance= numSteps*0.8;

            //Calories output
            count_calories.setText(String.format("%.2f", calories));
            total_energy=(0.985*SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()*weight);
            calories=total_energy/4.2;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DecimalFormat` to format `double` into `String`, e.g.:

```
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
double d = 3232.432432;
System.out.println(format.format(d));
```

Comment: it still gives me error "IllegalArgumentException: Bad class: class java.lang.String"

Comment: Can you try declaring `"#.##"` as a constant and then use it?

Comment: Same error but longer exception output
Edit: http://pastebin.com/9FC8tjB5 output for constant

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25067181/changing-date-format-stored-as-a-string

Comment: I still don't get it sorry

Comment: I think it has something to do with using strings in your android class. Once it gets sorted, the above answer will work fine..